# Populate text value when option selected from dropdown in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue` app and new to `vue`. I have a dropdown which is populated via an `axios` `endpoint`. This returns 2 items. What I'm trying to do is, if 'APC' is selected, then populate a `text` value with an attribute value returned in my `array` but this is where I may be overthinking.

My thinking is that I need to iterate over the items again but if a condition is met display the value.

Below is my whole page code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="courierList">Courier <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7 shipping-options">
                <select id="courierList" class="form-control" v-model="selectedCourier">
                    <option value='courierDefault'>Please select a courier</option>
                    <option :value="courier.name.toLowerCase()" v-for="(courier, index)  in couriers" :key="courier.index">
                        {{ courier.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span v-if="selectedCourier != 'courierDefault'">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <b class="col-sm-3" for="cutOff">Order cut-off</b>
                <div class="col-sm-7 shipping-options" v-for="(cutOff, index)  in couriers" :key="cutOff.index">
                    {{ cutOff.cut_off }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'CourierSelect',

        data() {
            return {
                couriers: [],
                selectedCourier: 'courierDefault'
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.fetchCouriers();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchCouriers() {
                axios.get('/CHANGED_FOR_SECURITY')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.couriers = response.data.couriers;
                    console.log('axios_couriers', this.couriers)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    VueEvent.$emit('show-error-modal', 'cartFethchCouriers');
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My `console.log` for 'axios_couriers' gives

[image]

Then when I select 'APC' my page displays as

[image]

But what I need is for the 'cut_off' value (displayed in the console screenshot) for the 'APC' `Array` `object` to display only. The value should be 16:30

Is there a way to do this as a `Computed` prop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested a `computed` should indeed work.
One way would be:

```js
currentCutOff() {
  return this.couriers.find(c => c.name == this.selectedCourier).cut_off;
}
```

This tries to find the courier from your array which equals the name of the currently selectedCourier.

Comment: I would just wrap the form in one `for loop` and you have access to the currently selected `curier` at both form element.

Comment: @ZedHome can you spin up a little codesandbox with your example to look at?

Comment: Check my answer below. Instead of binding `:value="courier.name.toLowerCase()"` with `v-model="selectedCourier"`, then using the name to look up `cut_off`, just bind `:value="courier` and you have the `selectedCourier.cut_off`.

Comment: and you can `selectedCurier.name.toLowerCase()` if you need it elsewhere

Comment: welp, my page didn't update on here and I didn't see your answer :( I missed the first v-for loop and thought the select was completely independent from the actual v-for, thus the computed. My bad, sorry!!  Murday should then indeed rewrite it to one for-loop and use the current iteration to get the correct cut_off and mark @ZedHome answer as correct. Mine is technically "correct" but his is more appropiate for what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simplier solution with vuejs data binding.
Check this code:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'AAA',
          time: '14:00'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'BBB',
          time: '18:00'
        }
      ],
      selected: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="null">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div>Selected: {{ selected? selected.time : 'nothing selected' }}</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't asking about `data-binding` as I had already got that done, I needed to populate a text value when my `select` was selected. No idea what you was trying to get at with this but it isn't relevant to my question. I know how to get and display the value of the selected `select`

Comment: The simplified code shows exatly that. You don't need to compute the currently selected object's `time` property. It is handled with `v-model="selected"` and `v-bind:value="item.time"`, and displayed.

Comment: Updated to bind the whole selected object, and handle initial `null` value of `selected`